# How to fix transparency issue of scroll able content on fixed position of bottom div and top div

Tags: html, css

I am designing chatbox and set the fixed position of top div and bottom div and in between there is one div that responsible for the content of the chat problem is that when the content exceeds scrolling will start but in fixed bottom position the content is showing in transparency in mobile and when I inspect the element, Please someone help.

```
//Top div fixed position
.header {   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    max-width:900px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    right:0px;  
    top:0px;   
    width:100%;   
    position: fixed;

}
//Bottom div fixed position
.type_msg {
    max-width:900px;
    border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;  
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    right:0px;  
    bottom:0px;   
    width:100%;   
    position: fixed;

}
//Content div with scroller
.msg_history {
max-width:900px;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
right:0px;  
top:78px;    
width:100%;   
position: fixed;
filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
height: 500px;  
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image]
Here's the output of my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give it z-index property which can help show input text and background text .
background-color:#fff;
z-index:999;

```css
class{
z-index:99;
background:#fff;}
```